# Passing Array of Objects OR Array of Arrays Between Python & C++ Library

Tags: python, arrays, ctypes

I've an `extern "C"` declaration of a C++ function, compiled as part of a shared library on Ubuntu, `getVPHistory`

```
void getVPHistory(actorPos allPostions[], uint numAct, uint numDim, uint numState) {
uint actorDimPairCount = numAct * numDim;
uint actorDimPairIndex = 0;
float val = 1.0;
for (uint actor = 0; actor < numAct; ++actor) {
  for (uint dim = 0; dim < numDim; ++dim) {
    actorPos *ap = &allPostions[actorDimPairIndex];
    ++actorDimPairIndex;
    ap->actor = actor;
    ap->dim = dim;
    ap->nState = numState;
    for (uint state = 0; state < numState; ++state) {
      ap->pos[state] = val;
      val += 0.5; // incrementing is just for testing
    }
  }
}
```

}

The `actorPos` object is defined as:

```
using actorPos = struct singleActorPositions {
  unsigned int actor;
  unsigned int dim;
  unsigned int nState;
  float pos[1000]; // possible upper limit of nState
```

};

I'm using `ctypes` in python to try to use this function, with the following code:

```
import ctypes as c

actorCnt = 2 dimensionCnt = 2; stateCnt = 2

smpLib = c.cdll.LoadLibrary('libsmpDyn.so')
class PosHist(c.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("actorID",c.c_uint),\
    ("dimensionID",c.c_uint),\
    ("stateCnt",c.c_uint),\
    ('positions',c.c_float*stateCnt)]
posHistArrType = PosHist*(actorCnt*dimensionCnt)

posHists = posHistArrType()

proto_PS = c.CFUNCTYPE(c.c_voidp,c.POINTER(posHistArrType),c.c_uint,c.c_uint,c.c_uint)
getVPHistory = proto_PS(('getVPHistory',smpLib))

getVPHistory(posHists,actorCnt,dimensionCnt,stateCnt)
```

This runs with no errors, but when I try to access the returned data inside `posHists`, I see that only the first object has been filled. Running this:

```
for p in posHists:
  print('Actor: %d, Dimension: %d'%(p.actorID,p.dimensionID))
  for o in p.positions:
    print('\t%0.2f'%o)
```

Gives me this:

```
Actor: 0, Dimension: 0
    1.00
    1.50
Actor: 0, Dimension: 0
    0.00
    0.00
Actor: 0, Dimension: 0
    0.00
    0.00
Actor: 0, Dimension: 0
    0.00
    0.00
```

I.e., after the first `PosHist` object in the array, all the others still show just the initial values. I can confirm that the `getVPHistory` function is completely filling out the array, so it seems to me an issue of the full array not getting passed back into my `posHists` variable.  Help please!

## EDIT

Suspecting the struct was part of the issue - and ultimately more than was needed for the problem - I've simplified this to just use a 3-d array. The C `getVPHistory` function is now:

```
  void getVPHistory(float hist[100][100][100], uint numAct, uint numDim, uint numState)
  {
    // talk a little
    cout << "Actors: " << numAct << "Dimensions: " << numDim << "States: " << numState << endl;
    
    // loop through all actors, dims, and states and store the positions
    float val = 1.0;
    for (uint actor = 0; actor < numAct; ++actor)
    {
      //cout << "Actor " << actor << endl;
      for (uint dim = 0; dim < numDim; ++dim)
      {
        //cout << "Dimension " << dim << endl;
        for (uint state = 0; state < numState; ++state)
        {
          hist[actor][dim][state] = val;
          cout << "A: " << actor << " D: " << dim << " S: " << state << "\tAdded position: " << val << endl;
          val += 0.5;
        }
      }
    }       
  }
```

and the python code is now:

```
actorCnt = 3; dimensionCnt = 2; stateCnt = 5
posHistType = ((c.c_float * stateCnt) * dimensionCnt)*actorCnt

proto_PS = c.CFUNCTYPE(c.c_voidp,c.POINTER(posHistType),c.c_uint,c.c_uint,c.c_uint)
getVPHistory = proto_PS(('getVPHistory',smpLib))

posHists = posHistType()
getVPHistory(posHists,actorCnt,dimensionCnt,stateCnt)

for a in range(actorCnt):
  for d in range(dimensionCnt):
    print('Pos Hist for Actor %d, Dimension %d:'%(a,d))
    print('\t[%s]'%', '.join(['%0.2f'%p for p in posHists[a][d]]))
```

So now I'm passing a pointer to memory for a 3-d array, the data is filled in in C, and then I read the data in python. Console output from C verifies that the data is being stored:

```
Actors: 3 Dimensions: 2 States: 5
A: 0 D: 0 S: 0  Added position: 1
A: 0 D: 0 S: 1  Added position: 1.5
A: 0 D: 0 S: 2  Added position: 2
A: 0 D: 0 S: 3  Added position: 2.5
...
A: 2 D: 1 S: 2  Added position: 14.5
A: 2 D: 1 S: 3  Added position: 15
A: 2 D: 1 S: 4  Added position: 15.5
```

Yet, even without the complication of the struct, I have the same issue of only the first inner-most array coming back with data:

```
Pos Hist for Actor 0, Dimension 0:
    [1.00, 1.50, 2.00, 2.50, 3.00]
Pos Hist for Actor 0, Dimension 1:
    [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00]
Pos Hist for Actor 1, Dimension 0:
    [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00]
Pos Hist for Actor 1, Dimension 1:
    [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00]
Pos Hist for Actor 2, Dimension 0:
    [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00]
Pos Hist for Actor 2, Dimension 1:
    [0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00]
```

If I hard code the array in the C function definition to be `hist[3][2][5]` - same as it's created in python - the same behavior occurs.

Comment: This `stateCnt = 2 ... ('positions',c.c_float*stateCnt)` somewhat does not seem to match `float pos[1000]`

Comment: If you specify an array length *within* a structure, you must always use the same length everywhere. You're laying them out in an *array*. Or, use a *pointer-to-structure* instead.

Comment: Thanks, but the `pos[1000]` can't be the issue, because the `getVPHistory()` function works fine when called in an identical way from C.  Anyway, I don't see how allocating enough memory for 1000 entries, then only filling in data for 2 would cause the passed back memory to only show data in 1!

Comment: Assuming the C compiler in use supports VLAs (a C++ compiler won't, BTW) try this: `void getVPHistory(uint numAct, uint numDim, uint numState, float hist[numAct][numDim][numSate]);` (order matters here)

Comment: Tried that @alk, no luck (using gcc).

Comment: What about using `void getVPHistory(uint numAct, uint numDim, uint numState, float (*hist)[numAct][numDim][numSate]);` and changing all `hist` to be `(*hist)`.

Comment: `pos[1000]` *is* the issue.  You have to declare the structure with the *same dimensions* between C++ and Python.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the structure with the *same dimensions* betweeen C++ and Python:

Working (Windows) C++ DLL:

```
typedef unsigned int uint;

struct actorPos
{
    unsigned int actor;
    unsigned int dim;
    unsigned int nState;
    float pos[1000]; // possible upper limit of nState
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
void getVPHistory(actorPos allPostions[], uint numAct, uint numDim, uint numState)
{
    uint actorDimPairIndex = 0;
    float val = 1.0;
    for(uint actor = 0; actor < numAct; ++actor)
    {
        for(uint dim = 0; dim < numDim; ++dim)
        {
            actorPos* ap = &allPostions[actorDimPairIndex];
            ++actorDimPairIndex;
            ap->actor = actor;
            ap->dim = dim;
            ap->nState = numState;
            for(uint state = 0; state < numState; ++state)
            {
                ap->pos[state] = val;
                val += 0.5; // incrementing is just for testing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Python code:

```
import ctypes as c

actorCnt = 2; dimensionCnt = 2; stateCnt = 2

smpLib = c.CDLL('test')
class PosHist(c.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("actorID",c.c_uint),\
    ("dimensionID",c.c_uint),\
    ("stateCnt",c.c_uint),\
    ('positions',c.c_float*1000)] # declare same size as struct in C++
posHistArrType = PosHist*(actorCnt*dimensionCnt)

posHists = posHistArrType()

proto_PS = c.CFUNCTYPE(c.c_voidp,c.POINTER(posHistArrType),c.c_uint,c.c_uint,c.c_uint)
getVPHistory = proto_PS(('getVPHistory',smpLib))

getVPHistory(posHists,actorCnt,dimensionCnt,stateCnt)

for p in posHists:
    print('Actor: %d, Dimension: %d'%(p.actorID,p.dimensionID))

    # Here, iterate only the number of states returned...
    for i in range(p.stateCnt):
        print('\t%0.2f'%p.positions[i])
```

Output:

```
Actor: 0, Dimension: 0
    1.00
    1.50
Actor: 0, Dimension: 1
    2.00
    2.50
Actor: 1, Dimension: 0
    3.00
    3.50
Actor: 1, Dimension: 1
    4.00
    4.50
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark-Tolonen.  As I got no useful answers for so long, I'd already moved on to a different solution which used only a regular flat array, which I then reshape into a structure like I want in Python.  As soon as I can, I'll test your solution so I can mark your answer.